# Relative XPath Wrongly Selects Same Element in Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm scraping some data.

One of the data points I need is the date, but the table cells containing this data only include months and days. Luckily the year is used as a headline element to categorize the tables.

For some reason `year = table.find_element(...)` is selecting the same element for every iteration.

I would expect `year = table.find_element(...)` to select ***unique elements relative to each unique*** `table` element as it loops through all of them, but this isn't the case.

**Actual Output**

```
# random, hypothetical values
Page #1
  element="921"
  element="921"
  element="921"
  ...
Page #2
  element="1283"
  element="1283"
  element="1283"
...
```

**Expected Output**

```
# random, hypothetical values
Page #1
  element="921"
  element="922"
  element="923"
  ...
Page #2
  element="1283"
  element="1284"
  element="1285"
...
```

**How come the following code selects the same element for every iteration on each page?**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

links_sc2 = [
  'https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Premier_Tournaments',
  'https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Major_Tournaments',
  'https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Minor_Tournaments',
  'https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Minor_Tournaments/HotS',
  'https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Minor_Tournaments/WoL'
]
ff = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\WebDriver\\geckodriver.exe')
urls = []

for link in links_sc2:
  tables = ff.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h2/following::table')
  for table in tables:
    try:
      # premier, major
      year = table.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h3/span').text
    except:
      # minor
      year = table.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2/span').text
    print(year)
ff.quit()
```

Comment: I'd have to research more to answer your question but I did find a locator that will locator the year much more simply... a CSS selector, `span.mw-headline[id^='20']`. I noticed that all the `SPAN` tags you wanted have an ID which is the year so you can do a `^=` (starts with) and search for '20'.

Comment: @JeffC the issue is not my selectors. the xpaths work fine in the browser console. the issue, however, is that for some reason the script seems to be re-using the same `table` element in the `table.find_element(...)` for each iteration. have no idea why :/

Comment: Understood... but the one locator I gave you will work on the Premier, Major, and Minor pages so you can skip the `try-except` and do a single find. My guess is the second find is causing the issue... so technically it is your locator.

Comment: You need to use `./preceding-sibling::h3[1]/span` for the nearest `h3` from the table

Comment: ^ That's probably it... but that will be different in different browsers because XPath implementations differ.

Comment: @JeffC ohh sorry, i misunderstood your comment. i wonder if i can write that as an `XPATH` selector instead like `./preceding-sibling::(h3|h2)/span.text`??

Comment: @Kamal i dont think thats it but ill try it anyways

Comment: @Kamal wow youre right. **why is that?** if i dont specify `[1]` it goes all the way back to the first `h3` or `h2` element?? i dont understand why that works. doesnt selenium always select `[1]` by default??

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. If you don't use indexing then it will return first result as per DOM order; but if you do use index then it starts from the nearest, once reached to first in DOM order, next will be following from context element.

Comment: @Kamal interesting. it makes sense. thanks so much. post the answer with that explanation and ill select it

Comment: Sorry, the part about "once reached to first in DOM order, next will be following from context element" is not correct, it just goes to preceding elements and not the next(following) elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `./preceding-sibling::h3[1]/span` to get the nearest `h3` sibling from the context element(your table).

The `preceding-sibling` works like this:

- `./preceding-sibling::h3` will return the first `h3` sibling in DOM
  order, which is year 2019 for you.
- But if you use indexing, then `./preceding-sibling::h3[1]` will
  return the nearest `h3` element from the context element and further
  indexing reaches to the next match in reverse of DOM order. You can also use `./preceding-sibling::h3[last()]` go get the farthest sibling.

Comment: it actually makes a lot of sense now that i think about it. because the `//h2/following::table/preceding-sibling::` context is just the initial starting point from which you can crawl the entire DOM. `[1]` simply selects the closest element to the provided context

Comment: @QHarr, sorry I don't understand your question clearly.

Comment: where does your line go in the original code please?

Comment: `year = table.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h3/span').text` will be `year = table.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h3[1]/span').text`.